# Download failed cURL error 7: . Can't update anything

Tags: updates, curl

Please, help. I want to update WordPress(or plugins), but always the same error: 'Download failed: cURL error 7: .'

> OS: Linux Fedora 30. Server: nginx. DB: MySQL 8.0. PHP 7.3

I have installed all the needed `PHP` extensions. Curl is working - I tested to download google HTML using curl and `info.php` says thas cURL is enabled.

Why WordPress can't update anything?  Nginx error.log does not have mistakes. On another laptop (Windows 10) with the same development environment, everything works.

What information should I give you to solve this problem?

[image: error on the WordPress site]

[image: cURL info (phpMyAdmin)]

Comment: Was it actually `curl (7)` i.e. 7 is the error code?

Comment: I think that it is error code but there is no error description as, for exmaple, 'could not connect to port' or something like this. Just installaition failed on a new string.

Comment: Thanks. That looks like this error is generated by wp-includes/Requests/Transport/cURL.php, which prints [curl_errno](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php). The documentation there links to [libcurl-errors](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html), and 7 = CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT: Failed to connect() to host or proxy.

Answer (score 3):

In my case (running on Centos 8), this error was caused by [SElinux](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/index) preventing `apache` (the login running the web server) from using the [`connect(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/connect) system call.

[Try running in permissive mode](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/changing-selinux-states-and-modes/#selinux-changing-to-permissive-mode) -- if that works, change your SELinux configuration as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow all outgoing connections from your hosting side. Ask your hosting provider to do that if you don't know how.
This will fix the issue.